# Link two dataTable Outputs in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to open one table from another without using extra tab. I have following code which makes 2 tables visible at the same time but I want the second one to be visible only once I click the first one. So, I think some kind of click(link) to make the second table visible is needed and until then only first table needs to be displayed.

```
set.seed(0)
mydf <- data.frame(Type = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 30, replace = TRUE),
                   Amount = sample(10:200, 30, replace = TRUE), 
                   stringsAsFactors= FALSE, check.names = FALSE)

mydf_agg <- aggregate(list(Amount=mydf$Amount),list(Type=mydf$Type),sum)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(width=3,status="primary",solidHeader=T,collapsible=T, title="Summary", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable_summary")),
    box(width=3,status="primary",solidHeader=T,collapsible=T, title="More Data", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"))
    
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable_summary <-  DT::renderDataTable({  mydf_agg })
  output$mytable <-  DT::renderDataTable({  mydf })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I need to click table1 to get to table2 and viceversa. click again should have same results.

Comment: yes, even switch tabs can help me, but I need to be able to click tables to move to different tabs/tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of `shinyjs` package `show`/`hide` functions here.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    box(width=3,status="primary",solidHeader=T,collapsible=T, title="Summary", 
        DT::dataTableOutput("mytable_summary")),
    box(width=3,status="primary",solidHeader=T,collapsible=T, title="More Data", 
        DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"))
    
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(flag = FALSE)
  output$mytable_summary <-  DT::renderDataTable({mydf_agg})
  output$mytable <-  DT::renderDataTable({  mydf })
  observeEvent(input$mytable_summary_cell_clicked, {
    if(rv$flag) show('mytable')
    else hide('mytable')
    rv$flag <- !rv$flag 
  })
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it before, I don't(can't install) have all the packages, I use R v3.4 and have limited packages. I have Shiny and ShinyDashboard.